# Configuration management server for java enterprice application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

We have an java enterprise application that is supposed to run on cluster of servers. The application consists of different WARs hosted by some web containers running on these servers.

Now  we have a lot of different configurations for this application, to name a few:

1. Relational DB host/port, credentials and so forth
2. Non Relational DB configurations - stuff like mongo, redis and so forth
3. Internal lookup configurations (how to obtain a web service in SOA architecture, stuff like that).
4. Logging related configuration, log4j.xml
5. Connection pooling configurations
6. Maybe in future some internal settings for smart load balancing, maybe Multi Tenancy support

Add to this multiple environments, test/staging/production/development and what not, having different hosts/ports for all aforementioned examples and we and up with a dozen of configuration files.

As I see it, all these things are not something related directly to the business layer of the application, but rather can be considered "generic" for all applications, at least in the java enterprise world.

So I'm wondering whether exists some solution for dealing with configuration management of this kind???

Basically I'm looking for the following abilities:

- Start my war on any of my servers in cluster with a host/port of this configuration server.
- The war will "register" itself and "download" all the needed configurations. Of course it will have adapters to apply this configuration.
- This way, all my N wars in different JVMs in cluster start (they're all share-nothing architecture, so I consider them as independent pieces of deployment)
- Now, if I want to change some setting, like, setting the log level of some logger to DEBUG, I go to the management console UI of this configuration server and apply the change. 
  Since this management center knows about all the wars (as they were registered), it should notify them about the setting change. I want to be able to change settings for one specific WAR or cluster wide. If one of the web servers that hosts the application gets restarted it will again ask for configuration and will get the configuration including the DEBUG level of that logger.

  - I'm not looking for solution based on deployment systems like puppet, chef and so forth since I want to change my settings during the runtime as well.

So far I couldn't find any descent ready solution for this. Of course I can craft something like that by myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, So I'm asking for advice here, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might like Apache [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

Comment: Yes, thanks Elliott. I'm aware of ZooKeeper, its nice, and if I'll opt for "craft by myself" solution it possibly will be implemented on top of ZooKeeper, although I think that I don't need here concurrent writes, since the only way to modify the application would be a dedicated UI on some management console (as I see it).

Comment: I have almost identical needs, so I'm considering writing one myself. Before I jump on that train have you had any luck on finding or crafting something yourself?

Comment: Well. This one was postponed actually in my case. But it seems like zoo keeper is really my best bet here. Another solution is stuff like eureka from a netflix suit of services i guess but i'm not totally sure it will suite my needs.